# Import.io - Can it replace Kimonolabs

Tags: web-scraping, import.io

I use Kimonolabs right now for scraping data from websites that have the same goal. To make it easy, lets say these websites are online shops selling stuff online (actually they are job websites with online application possibilities, but technically it looks a lot like a webshop).

This works great. For each website an scraper-API is created that goes trough the available advanced search page to crawl all product-url's. Let's call this API the 'URL list'. Then a 'product-API' is created for the product-detail-page that scrapes all necessary elements. E.g. the title, product text and specs like the brand, category, etc. The product API is set to crawl daily using all the URL's gathered in the 'URL list'.

Then the gathered information for all product's is fetched using Kimonolabs JSON endpoint using our own service.

However, Kimonolabs will quit its service end of february 2016 :-(. So, I'm looking for an easy alternative. I've been looking at import.io, but I'm wondering:

- Does it support automatic updates (letting the API scrape hourly/daily/etc)?
- Does it support fetching all product-URL's from a paginated advanced search page?

I'm tinkering around with the service. Basically, it seems to extract data via the same easy proces as Kimonolabs. Only, its unclear to me if paginating the URL's necesarry for the product-API and automatically keeping it up to date are supported.

Any import.io users here that can give advice if import.io is a usefull alternative for this? Maybe even give some pointers in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

Look into [Portia](http://scrapinghub.com/portia). It's an [open source](https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia) visual scraping tool that works like Kimono.

Portia is also available as a service and it fulfills the requirements you have for import.io:

- automatic updates, by scheduling periodic jobs to crawl the pages you want, keeping your data up-to-date.
- navigation through pagination links, based on URL patterns that you can define.

Full disclosure: I work at Scrapinghub, the lead maintainer of Portia.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to give [Extracty](https://extracty.com) a try. Its a free web scraping tool that allows you to create endpoints that extract any information and return it in JSON. It can easily handle paginated searches.

If you know a bit of JS you can write CasperJS Endpoints and integrate any logic that you need to extract your data. It has a similar goal as Kimonolabs and can solve the same problems (if not more since its programmable).

If [Extracty](https://extracty.com) does not solve your needs you can checkout these other market players that aim for similar goals:

- Import.io (as you already mentioned)
- Mozenda
- Cloudscrape
- TrooclickAPI
- FiveFilters

*Disclaimer: I am a co-founder of the company behind Extracty.*

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that much fond of Import.io, but seems to me it allows pagination through bulk input urls. Read [here](http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/261209-can-i-paginate-through-results-using-an-extractor).

So far not much progress in getting the whole website thru API:

> Chain more than one API/Dataset It is currently not possible to fully automate the extraction of a whole website with Chain API. 
>   For example if I want data that is found within category pages or paginated lists. I first have to create a list of URLs, run Bulk Extract, save the result as an import data set, and then chain it to another Extractor.Once set up once, I would like to be able to do this in one click more automatically.

P.S. If you are somehow familiar with JS you might find [this](https://webscraping.pro/writing-next-generation-scraping-scripts-with-web-robots-ide/) useful.

Comment: The problem is, I'm only fluent in HTML and CSS. Coding isn't something I specialize in. Kimonolabs was great for this because it enabled running daily/hourly automated productlists and then automatically scraped these active products. Alle active products then outputted via JSON to our own service. I really hope I can find something like this as a web-service. Maybe somebody here has a good alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding automatic updates:
This is a [beta feature](http://support.import.io/forums/199278-ideas-forum/suggestions/4829425-scheduled-apis-schedule-a-web-crawl-task-every-x) right now. I'm testing this for myself after migrating from kimonolabs...You can enable this for your own APIs by appending `&bulkSchedule=1` to your API URL. Then you will see a "Schedule" tab. In the "Configure" tab select "Bulk Extract" and add your URLs after this the scheduler will run daily or weekly.